# Connecting to WiFi using adb shell

Tags: android, linux, adb

I have all the details to connect to a particular access point. I have to use that access point only, so all I require is the command to do it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I have to automate a few things which only work with wi-fi.I can use monkey and click on settings->etc., but last thing would be how do i choose the network ABC as there may be more than one networks available. so if i could get a command, i can do that using SSID and password right away :)

Comment: To complement the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282484/android-adb-turn-on-wifi-via-adb

Comment: I updated the wpa_supplicant.conf file with new SSID and password, enabled the wifi but this doesn't seem to work on Nexus 4, Lolipop build. Wifi turns on but goes back to original SSID, that I was using via UI. I also noticed that my updated file was over written with the earlier SSID. I have change chown to system.wifi . Am I doing something incorrect here? I saw some post talking about sqlite3. Do we need to change anything in db?

Comment: wpa_cli way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825443/connect-to-password-protected-wifi-network-using-adb-shell

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add a network entry into the wpa_supplicant.conf yourself (or within your script) Essentially connect manually once, then do:

```
adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and integrate the network entry into your script for automation. Example simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# Get this information by connecting manually once, and do
#   adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
ADB_PULL="adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf"
WIRELESS_CTRL_INTERFACE=wlan0
WIRELESS_SSID=Gondolin
WIRELESS_KEY_MGMT="WPA-EAP IEEE8021X"
WIRELESS_EAP=PEAP
WIRELESS_USER=Turgon
WIRELESS_PASSWORD=IdrilCelebrindal

adb start-server
adb wait-for-device
echo "adb connection....[CONNECTED]"
adb root
adb wait-for-device
adb remount
adb wait-for-device

pushd /tmp
rm wpa_supplicant.conf 2>/dev/null # Remove any old one
adbpull_status=`$ADB_PULL 2>&1`
echo -e "\nAttempting: $ADB_PULL"
if [ `echo $adbpull_status | grep -wc "does not exist"` -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "  wpa_supplicant.conf does not exist yet on your device yet."
    echo "This means you have not used your wireless yet."
    echo ""
    echo "Taking our best shot at creating this file with default config.."

    echo "ctrl_interface=$WIRELESS_CTRL_INTERFACE" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
    echo "update_config=1" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
    echo "device_type=0-00000000-0" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
else
    echo $adbpull_status
    echo "  wpa_supplicant.conf exists!"
fi

echo ""
echo "Add network entry for wpa_supplicant.conf.."
echo "" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "network={" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "  ssid=\"$WIRELESS_SSID\"" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "  key_mgmt=$WIRELESS_KEY_MGMT" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "  eap=$WIRELESS_EAP" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "  identity=\"$WIRELESS_USER\"" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "  password=\"$WIRELESS_PASSWORD\"" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "  priority=1" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "}" >> wpa_supplicant.conf
echo "Pushing wpa_supplicant.conf.."
adb push wpa_supplicant.conf /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
popd #/tmp

adb shell chown system.wifi /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
adb shell chmod 660 /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

echo ""
echo "Finished!"
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings
echo "Please toggle wifi off/on now.. (ifconfig not sufficient, monkey this)"
```

Comment: One could just use: `wpa_passphrase ssid passphrase` on an Ubuntu box and copy the output to the android device. It has worked for me on a samsung tablet.

Comment: Yes for rooted devices. But it really helped me to unlock my devices. Thank you very-much for useful paths. Instead of toggling through settings I used `svc wifi disable` and then `svc wifi enable`.

Comment: after 4 hours of intensive  searching for solution how to connect to wifi, where absolutely nothing worked, this solution was the magic-spell! Also added edit suggestion for svc restart, like @ony suggests

Answer (score 32):

Late to the party, but I came up with a way to accomplish this on a device **without root**.

It may not be pretty, but it works.

Basically what I propose is to create an app that joins an access point based on `EXTRAS` given when starting the app.
The `EXTRAS` are then provided using the `am` command's `-e <KEY> <VALUE>` parameter.

I already build an app which does so and it's available here: https://github.com/steinwurf/adb-join-wifi

Once the app is installed, a wifi access point can be joined using the following `ADB` command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.steinwurf.adbjoinwifi/com.steinwurf.adbjoinwifi.MainActivity -e ssid [SSID] -e password_type [PASSWORD_TYPE] -e password [WIFI PASSWORD]
```

There's more info in the README on Github.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thank you for this - great idea!

Comment: @JulianFrumar how to know the password type of router?

Comment: @Suban Dhyako It should tell you in your router settings what type of password/security it's using. Also, in the android wifi screen, if you tap on a network it will tell you the security type. Most routers these days will be set up as WPA2 or WPA, and it seems that typing WPA in the adb command will work for either WPA or WPA2.  Also, as a note to the author, this worked wonderfully, thank you. But the multi-line command formatting on the github didn't work for me, while the single line command here did.

Comment: @gamingexpert13 thanks, glad to hear it worked for you. The multiline is probably only working on Linux :)

Comment: hey man I am trying to use your app but when I run the command it says "This application is meant to be used with ADB" what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @dam1ne, as far as I remember, the message is shown when you start the application on your phone from the launcher.
This app is meant to be started from ADB. Did you follow the instructions in the readme: https://github.com/steinwurf/adb-join-wifi/blob/master/README.rst#usage

Answer (score 14):

You can use the command adb shell cmd -w wifi connect-network with these parameters

```
-  connect-network  open|owe|wpa2|wpa3 [] [-m] [-d] [-b ] [-r auto|none|persistent|non_persistent]
    Connect to a network with provided params and add to saved networks list
    open|owe|wpa2|wpa3 - Security type of the network.
     - SSID of the network
        - Use 'open' or 'owe' for networks with no passphrase
           - 'open' - Open networks (Most prevalent)
           - 'owe' - Enhanced open networks
        - Use 'wpa2' or 'wpa3' for networks with passphrase
           - 'wpa2' - WPA-2 PSK networks (Most prevalent)
    -m - Mark the network metered.
           - 'wpa3' - WPA-3 PSK networks
    -d - Mark the network autojoin disabled.
    -h - Mark the network hidden.
    -p - Mark the network private (not shared).
    -b  - Set specific BSSID.
    -r auto|none|persistent|non_persistent - MAC randomization scheme for the network
```

To connect to a wifi network 'Home' with a wpa2 authentication and passphrase as 'qwertyuiop' use

```
adb shell cmd -w wifi connect-network Home wpa2 qwertyuiop
```

To connect to an open wifi network 'Public' use

```
adb shell cmd -w wifi connect-network Public open
```

Comment: in my phone, the commond work is `adb shell cmd wifi`, without `-w`

Comment: there is no -h param in my devices. Why this happens

Comment: my wifi SSID/name has spaces and a ! in it. 'Fr!tzBox 3423' How do I pass that? It gives Invalid args for connect-network: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown network type 3423

Comment: the solution to escape space in SSID is to use \. The command would become `adb shell cmd wifi connect-network 'FRITZ!Box\ 3423' wpa2 password123`

Comment: A special plus is that this doesn't need the device PIN, just ADB (which has to be granted access previously).

Answer (score 11):

As an add-on:
you can enable wifi via [svc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc) as root on the device

```
svc wifi enable
```

and disable via

```
svc wifi disable
```

Comment: This requires the device to be rooted and we should not suggest users to root the device because of security reasons.

Comment: @RajA.P.: Thank you for the feedback. Seemingly all methods except [@jpihl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303412/1587329)'s require the device to be rooted, they just did not say this explicitly. If the downvote was from you: did you downvote them all?

Comment: I had tried the above commands which said me the device to be rooted and I am using my enterprise device, which i dont want to compromise.

Comment: @RajA.P.: in that case, the above answer by jpihl might just work (as you see, this answer is a bit older)

Comment: Whether  you can use this or not depends on the device. I can use this on my S21 FE, but I'm not allowed `cmd wifi connect-network`.

Answer (score 3):

As an another add-on: although my device was rooted I got 
`remote object ''/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf'' does not exist` error while trying to execute `adb pull`. It happens because `adb` itself doesn't run in ROOT mode. To work this around you can execute something like this

```
adb shell "su -c 'cp -R /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf /data/misc/wpa_supplicant.conf'"
adb shell "su -c 'chmod -R 777 /data/misc/wpa_supplicant.conf'"
adb pull /data/misc/wpa_supplicant.conf
adb shell "su -c 'rm /data/misc/wpa_supplicant.conf'"
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem by this:
`adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf ~/Desktop`,and then edit the file, add network module, my whole conf file is:

```
##### wpa_supplicant configuration file template #####
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=DIR=/data/system/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wifi
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=1
fast_reauth=1
network={
    ssid="your ssid"
    psk="your pswd"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=241
}
```

Then rm the origin file, add push it to `/data/misc/wifi` folder, reboot your device.Please note, different device has different content above the network line，don't modify that part.

Answer (score 2):

super late but i hope this'll help anybody who may stumble upon this thread.

if you're trying the adb pull method but received "remote object does not exist", try this:

in the same command prompt box,

- type `adb root` to restart adb as root. click enter.
- Now type `adb shell`, click enter. makes sure the prompt shows `root@[device]:`
- At the # prompt type `cd /data/misc/wifi` click enter.
- Lastly type `cat wpa_supplicant.conf` click enter.

this should dump data of WiFi you've previously connected to on your phone, to your pc screen.

these commands worked on my unrooted device after running into the “remote object does not exist” issue.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>adb shell........................................................
shell@android:/ $ cd /data/misc/wifi.............................................‌​....................‌​....................‌​...........
/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/misc/wifi: Permission denied......................................................‌​.............
2|shell@android:/ $ cat wpa_supplicant.conf.........................................‌​....................‌​..................

Comment: /system/bin/sh: cat: wpa_supplicant.conf: No such file or directory.................................................
1|shell@android:/ $ cd /data/misc/wifi.............................................‌​................................................
/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/misc/wifi: Permission denied......................................................‌​.........

Comment: that is what i get when i run those commands :( . i have a samsung galaxy camera. android version 4.1.2. Maybe there is a security bug and i can use it and retrieve the wifi passwords?

Comment: Works only on rooted devices :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this to

Connect:

```
adb shell svc wifi enable
```

Disconnect:

```
adb shell svc wifi disable
```