# what is the key_code to enable or disable wifi via adb for non rooted device

Tags: adb, appium

I have a non rooted Samsung device , i want to enable/disable wi-fi settings for my usages via adb.To open wifi for non rooted device via adb i ran below command

```
adb  -s 4d0075754fdb41cd shell  am start -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
```

By default the wifi is coming as diabled , i want to enable/disable it

I tried with **Keyevent** , however this did not helped much

```
adb shell input keyevent 22
```

The wi-fi slider looks like below , i tried with all available **key_code** .
Can anyone point me a way to get the correct keycode here!!

[image: wifi settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `adb -s $PHONESERIAL shell "svc wifi enable"` if you just want to turn on the wifi with adb.

Was already answered here : [android adb turn on wifi via adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282484/android-adb-turn-on-wifi-via-adb/13652723)

Answer (score 0):

You placed appium tag, so if you using appium, try running:

```
adb -s $device_id shell am broadcast -a io.appium.settings.wifi --es setstatus enable
adb -s $device_id shell am broadcast -a io.appium.settings.wifi --es setstatus disable
```