# Connect to password protected wifi network using adb shell

Tags: android, networking, wifi, adb, access-point

I have an Android phone, and the goal is to connect the phone to a password protected wifi network.

Steps I know so far:

```
adb root
adb shell svc wifi enable
```

Ok sweet, wifi is turned on.
Now I need to connect the phone a certain wireless network that requires a password.
I am hoping I can connect using an adb shell command.

Any help?

I would rather not download programs onto the device

Comment: IF you really have root, you probably can insert a new record into whatever database of access points it has, but it will be tricky.  Can you configure the database manually, and only activate it with ADB?

Comment: There is no such thing like a database of access points. Android keeps it's list of configured AP's in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file (might be different for different OEM's and even phone models). Even though the easiest way would be to change this file by adding a new network block, the recommended approach is to use wpa_cli, wpa_supplicant command line interface. Check my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is possible to achieve using `wpa_cli`, command line interface of `wpa_supplicant`:

```
# Get to the shell
adb root
adb shell

# Get to wpa_cli prompt
wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wifi/sockets/ -i wlan0

# Add new WiFi network
add_network
set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN
set_network 0 key_mgmt WPA-PSK
set_network 0 ssid "network_name"
set_network 0 proto RSN
set_network 0 mode 0
set_network 0 psk "password"

# Connect to it
select_network 0
enable_network 0
reassociate

# Check the status
status
```

In the above list of commands, `add_network` command will output the index of the new network, which should be used for the subsequent commands. In this example, this index is `0`.

Comment: Thanks that helped. It looks like you got psk and ssid the wrong way around.

Comment: Are the options to `wpa_cli` required? On my phone I did not have to use any options to add a network.

Comment: Hi, now in Android 8, wpa_cli command is not present, is there any alternatives?

Comment: @Cu635 There's a high chance it is located in a directory which is not in your PATH. I'd advise you to search for `wpa_cli` binary in `/vendor` and other directories. Of course, there's a chance OEM has removed `wpa_cli` binary from user builds, but highly unlikely. Also, there's basically no alternative to `wpa_supplicant` (except `iw`, but it's new, and I'm sure no OEM would make a device in [2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_8.0_Oreo) with `iw` instead of `wpa_supplicant`).

Answer (score 1):

Use this procedure [more details included :) ]

1- Make sure wpa_supplicant is running. Look for its pid using this command:

```
pidof wpa_supplicant
```

This command should return the pid of wpa_supplicant process. If nothing returned, wpa_supplicant is not running. Use svc command to turn off wifi and then turned it on again:

```
svc wifi disable
svc wifi enable
```

2- Read **control interface** directory from wpa_supplicant.conf file. This file usually exists in /data/misc/wifi/. Open this file using cat command:

```
cat /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

update_config=1
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wpa_supplicant
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=1
fast_reauth=1
```

**Note:** to find wpa_supplicant.conf file you can search using find command in root directory. Goto root directory using cd / command and use find command to find wpa_supplicant.conf:

find . -name wpa_supplicant.conf

Go to control interface directory specified by ctrl_interafce. First file in this directory is the **interface name**.

```
cd /data/misc/wpa_supplicant
ls
wlan0
```

You are going to need "control interface" and "interface name" for executing wpa_cli command.

**Note:** if you incorrectly input these 2 parameters for wpa_cli command, the wpa_cli could not connect to wpa_supplicant and returns this message:

```
Interactive mode

Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: plan - re-trying
```

Or it may connect to wpa_supplicant but return UNKNOW COMMAND for its interactive commands like this:

```
> scan
UNKNOWN COMMAND
>add_network
UNKNOWN COMMAND
```

3- Execute wpa_cli command using above mentioned parameters:

```
wpa_cli -p [control directory path] -i [interface name]
wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wpa_supplicant -i wlan0
```

This commands then enter to interactive mode where you can scan and find networks, attach to them and ...

```
# Add new WiFi network
add_network
set_network 0 auth_alg OPEN
set_network 0 key_mgmt WPA-PSK
set_network 0 ssid "network_name"
set_network 0 proto RSN
set_network 0 mode 0
set_network 0 psk "password"

# Connect to it
select_network 0
enable_network 0
reassociate

# Check the status
status

save_config
```

Using save_config you can store these settings back into the wpa_supplicant.conf file for future use.
You can recall these setting next time by enable_network command. Next time you want to enable wifi use these commands:

```
wpa_cli -p /data/misc/wpa_supplicant -i wlan0

enable network 0
```

0 is network id. You can use list_networks to find other stored configurations.
For further information regarding wpa_cli refer to this document:
Also full interactive commands of wpa_cli is documented in this page.

http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README

I used this procedure for configuring wifi on Android on Orange Pi 2G IOT.