# How to delete a network profile from etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf through command line / shell script

Tags: linux, node.js, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have multiple wifi network ssid's saved in my etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf like shown below,
 can we delete a specific network from this wpa_supplicant.conf

Ex: in the below networks can a delete the network myssid1 through a shell script which i can then execute through node.js server

```
 network={
            ssid="myssid1"
            scan_ssid=0
            proto=WPA
            key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
            psk=5f55a9b869e9ab6d03839cae23c7243accc0ac0a12079d358328bf73ad2e0ebe
    }
    network={
           ssid="myssid2"
           scan_ssid=0
           proto=WPA
           key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
           psk=d89660510d06bbf7691f5296daae36872d697a88876c53db7de91aa85df4f68b
    }
    network={
           ssid="myssid3"
           scan_ssid=0
           proto=WPA
           key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
           psk=d635b33481a13b28a67e8964f58343cb19bc8c85c67cc56ee9bfe0c302914a5f
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i was able to get it done with the below script:

```
SSID_TO_DELETE=$1 
sed -n "1 !H 1 h $ { x s/[[:space:]]*network={\n[[:space:]]*ssid=\"${SSID_TO_DELETE}\"[^}]*}//g p }" /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf > /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 16):

using `wpa_cli` you can do this:

1:

```
wpa_cli remove_network 0
```

where `0` is the network_id you get after running `wpa_cli add_network`. It will remove the network and disconnect any interface using it.

**Note that the `network id` is not the order of the network in the file. you can get configured network using `wpa_cli list_networks`**

2:

```
wpa_cli save_config
```

This will persist the changes and the corresponding network block will be removed from `etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: Thank you ! my squeezebox radio was driving me nuts !!

Answer (score 0):

You can write it you're self. Some very ugly Quick-n-Dirty Code would be for example:

```
file="/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
foo="$(cat "$file" | awk '/myssid3/ { flag=1 }; flag==0 { print $0 }; /network={/ { flag=0 }' )"
if echo -e "$foo" | tail -1 | grep -q 'network={'; then
   foo=$(echo -e "$foo" | head -n -1)
fi
echo -e "$foo" > "$file"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, is there a way to do the same with node.js?

Comment: I tried this code and i get the error : No such file or directorya_supplicant.conf
myfile.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

```
SSID=$1 
temp_var=$(sudo awk -v RS= '!/${SSID}/{printf $0""RT}' etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf)
echo -e "$temp_var" | sudo tee etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The temp var is needed because this is the easiest way I found to actually make awk write to he file its processing.
To see the effect of changing wpa_supplicant.conf, do

```
svc wifi disable && svc wifi enable
```

Some references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18955226/1246369
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89707/172003
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=981258#3