# How does Android store WiFi connection information

Tags: android

How does Android (particularly v5.x) store WiFi connection information? Or how can it be read/written? I'm interested because I'd like to work around an issue where it keeps forgetting the static IP and password settings for my router.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not very relevant any more, but on my 5.1.1 actual WiFi connection configuration is saved to:
/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
In some cases it could be saved to:
/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

If not there, check other files in these directories.

You can modify this file on the fly and restart WiFi to actually 'apply' these changes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37433028/1246369