# Flight mode enable/disable programmatically in Appium for Android

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

Anybody has a working example how to manipulate with flight mode in Appium for Android? Appim docu is for this topic for some reason not complete, none of proposed ways works, together with "this should work....".
I am stuck with flight mode.

Comment: This question has been answered here.
[Answer:-how to automate the airplane mode in appium automation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62050475/10553774)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium documention is uncomplete on many issues, my both working methods for dealing with flight mode an and wifi are here:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void pressFlightMode(int waitingTime){
    if (isIOS()) {
        //should be implemented
    } else {
    try {
            ((AndroidDriver)driver).toggleAirplaneMode();
            sleep(waitingTime);
        } catch (Exception e ) {
            System.out.println("Error turning on flight mode.");
     }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void pressWifi(int waitingTime){
    if (isIOS()) {
        //to be implemented     
        } else {
            try {
                ((AndroidDriver)driver).toggleWifi();            
                sleep(waitingTime);
            } catch (Exception e ) {
                System.out.println("Error turning off flight mode.");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per appium documentation you can toggle airplane mode as mentioned below.

```
driver.toggleAirplaneMode();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Latest Android version permission disabled for enabled and disable Airplane mode, but you can achieve using below commands
In Appium Latest Java client you can do it using

**To disable Wifi and Data in Android:**

driver.setConnection(new ConnectionStateBuilder().withWiFiDisabled().withDataDisabled().build());

**To enabled WiFI and Data in Android:**
driver.setConnection(new ConnectionStateBuilder().withWiFiEnabled().withDataEnabled().build());

Comment: this works in emulator but not in real device

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not familiar with Appium, but you didn't mention if you've looked for solutions outside the appium.io documentation. I'm guessing `driver.toggleAirplaneMode()` hasn't worked for you?

In that case, have you tried converting the Python code in [this answer from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38332033/11108333)?

```
# To enable/disable flight mode
def enableFlightMode(self,context):
        driver.mobile.set_network_connection(driver.mobile.AIRPLANE_MODE)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        if driver.network_connection == 1:
            self.report_pass("The network connection is disabled in the mobile and flight mode is active.")
        else:
            self.report_fail("The flight mode is not active yet!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Appium documentation has a pretty [solid introduction](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/network-connection/) on how to change Connection type.

Java API is [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/android/SupportsNetworkStateManagement.java) and [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/android/connection/HasNetworkConnection.java)

`driver.getConnection()` will return you current state and then you can change it to needed one.

Note: Changing Airplane Mode state on real devices only works for Android 6 and older