# removing saved wifi network using adb command in rooted device

Tags: android, networking, adb, android-wifi

How can I remove the saved wi-fi network from my rooted android device?

I have tried copying the custom **wpa_supplicant.conf** file to **/data/misc/wifi/**

```
>adb push wpa_supplicant.conf /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The file copied successfully but it won't remove the saved wi-fi network.

I have following content in the custom wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets
disable_scan_offload=1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1p2p_device=1use_multi_chan_concurrent=1
update_config=1
device_name=Tablet
manufacturer=MSI
model_name=550-18900(MiniTouch)
model_number=550-18900(MiniTouch)
serial_number=0123456789ABCDEF
device_type=10-0050F204-5
config_methods=physical_display virtual_push_button
pmf=1
external_sim=1
```

I also tried removing wpa_supplicant.conf file.
I also tried turning off wifi and then pushing custom wpa_supplicant.conf file. I am not able to a removed the saved wifi network.

Comment: I have the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70025149/2267817

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the alternative way to remove the saved network from rooted device. This can be achieved using **wpa_cli** command.

```
$adb shell wpa_cli list_networks
//this will show the list like following
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0       worldink_wifi        any     [CURRENT]
//now you can remove the network using its network id
```

Then you can remove network using

```
$adb shell wpa_cli remove_network 0
//0 is network id
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
This yields the error message:
"Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: Operation not permitted", So I tried to do it as a super user (ran "su", then the list snippet), and got the error weird message:
 "Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: Success"

Comment: On a rooted Android Q device the error is instead: wpa_cli: inaccessible or not found, so seems like this is gone or something.

Comment: Not working. Here is my code `val command = "adb shell wpa_cli remove_network $netId" ;

        val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "-c", command))`

Answer (score 0):

Install adb, and connect your device and execute the following command :

```
adb shell am start -n 'com.adbwifisettingsmanager/.WifiSettingsManagerActivity' --esn remove -e ssid <ssid_name>
```

Replace the <ssid_name> with the name of the wifi network.