# Connecting Intel Edison running Android Things to the wifi

Tags: android, intel-edison, android-things

I have been trying to connect my Intel Edison running Android things to the Wifi. I was able to connect to a hotspot that did not require an identity using the code below:

`$ adb shell am startservice \
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect \
    -e ssid <Network_SSID> \
    -e passphrase <Network_Passcode>`

However is there a way to add an identity/username as an extra? This is required to connect to a specific Wifi network.

Thanks!

Comment: you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9368211/413127 it allows you to add an `identity` and `password`

Comment: Thanks, I took a look at the other thread and tried running the command adb pull /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf but I get the error: remote object does not exist. I also tried running it as su as mentioned in another comment but I get su not found. I ran the first command on a different Android phone connected to the actual AP I am trying to access to on the Edison board.

Comment: you won't have su on the phone, but you will on the edison board, try it on the board

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get su to work on the board by running "adb shell" > "su" and then going into the directory to take a look at the wpa_supplicant.conf file. However (following the answer from Maxim Sultakov on the thread) moving the file to a different directory and changing the permissions to 777, I still wasn't able to run adb pull.