# WIFI connection using adb

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi, wifi

I am trying to connect to wifi using adb as my android device is not connected to  any scree.

I did as following:

Modified the file data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=wlan0
update_config=1
manufacturer=XXInc.
device_name=Wireless Client
model_name=MTK Wireless Model
model_number=1.0
serial_number=2.0
device_type=XX-XXXX-5
os_version=01020300
config_methods=display push_button keypad
p2p_no_group_iface=1
driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1
hs20=1
network={
   ssid="MYSSDID"
   psk="MYPASSWORD"
   scan_ssid=1 
}
```

My questions are:

how can I add encryption type: `WPA/WPA2 PSK` to my file
and how can I start the connection?

I tried :

```
 adb shell am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService -a WifiSetupService.Connect -e ssid <your_ssid> -e passphrase <your_password>
```

but it does not find the service:

```
Starting service: Intent { act=WifiSetupService.Connect cmp=com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService }
Error: Not found; no service started.
```

this is what I found related to wifi

```
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6481:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$AlertReasonCount
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6482:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$ConnectionEvent
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6483:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$RouterFingerPrint
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6484:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$RssiPollCount
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6485:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$SoftApDurationBucket
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6486:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$SoftApReturnCodeCount
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6487:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$StaEvent
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6488:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$StaEvent$ConfigInfo
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6489:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$WifiLog
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6490:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$WifiLog$ScanReturnEntry
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6491:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$WifiLog$WifiSystemStateEntry
./system/etc/compiled-classes:6492:com.android.server.wifi.nano.WifiMetricsProto$WifiScoreCount
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to wi-fi using adb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708886/connecting-to-wi-fi-using-adb-shell)

Answer (score -1):

This should work i guess

```
 adb shell am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService -a WifiSetupService.Connect -e ssid <your_ssid> -e passphrase <your_password>
```

Comment: I tried it but I get : XXX:/ # am startservice -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService -a WifiSetupService.Connect -e ssid XXX -e passphrase ZZZZ
Starting service: Intent { act=WifiSetupService.Connect cmp=com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService (has extras) }
Error: Not found; no service started.