# Changing the Wifi name for a Virtual Android Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

The Android Virtual Device is connected by defualt to a wifi network called "AndroidWifi". I am working with an app that expects to be connected to a wifi network with a particular name.

How can I change the name of the wifi network from "AndroidWifi"?

Comment: AndroidWifi is a simulated access point by the avd so far i dont think there is any way to change this name.

Answer (score 2):

Try something more pragmatic:

```
String getExpectedId() {
    String ssid = this.getResources().getString(R.string.default_ssid);
    if(Build.FINGERPRINT.contains("generic")) {ssid = "AndroidWifi";}
    return ssid;
}
```

because you won't change the SSID (service set identifier) of the emulator's WiFi.

---

Despite there's `adb` commands alike `svc wifi enable` and `svc wifi disable`, the password for the default network likely is unknown in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`; see [Connecting to WiFi using adb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708886/connecting-to-wi-fi-using-adb-shell). Since the emulator is rooted, one can generally configure any network alike that, while it is accessible (which the regular WiFi, which is exists in reality, obviously isn't). I think the first one approach is better, because editing emulator images isn't too portable.

Answer (score 0):

AVD manager doesn't provide any ways to customize the simulated Wi-Fi access point AndroidWifi .

You may have to disable it and use another wifi simulator such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chylek.adam.fakewifi&hl=en). It does need the Xposed framework in order to function. [Here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) is how you can configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `hostapd.conf` file in your device (`/data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/hostapd.conf`). It will allow you to set ssid (`ssid=`) or even to set a password (`wpa_passphrase`). You will need a root access to do that.

More details at https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hostapd#WiFi_Technology